# I want to output stocks between transaction date, if no transaction date it should still display all stock on MySQL for inventory sys

Tags: mysql

My current query:

```
select stock.id, stock.name, sum(amount) from stock
left join stock_detail on stock.id = stock_detail.stock_id
where transact_at BETWEEN ('2018-06-15') and ('2018-06-16')
group by stock.id
```

but it wont display the other stock that has has no entry on stock detail table.

Table 1: Stock

```
id   name
1    chicken
2    beef
3    pork
4    drink
```

Table 2: StockDetail

```
id  stock_id    type    amount  transact_date   
1   1           in      1000    15/06/2018  
2   1           in      500     15/06/2018  
3   2           in      300     16/06/2018
```

I want Output

```
id      name       total_amount 
1       chicken    1500
2       beef       300
3       pork       0
4       drink      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the date predicate from `WHERE` to `ON`:

```
select stock.id, stock.name, coalesce(sum(amount) , 0)
from stock
left join stock_detail 
   on stock.id = stock_detail.stock_id 
      and transact_date BETWEEN ('2018-06-15') and ('2018-06-16')
group by stock.id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41306/3)

Comment: @webdev Glad I was able to help. Please accept this, or any other, answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Giorgos Bestos oh i forgot one more thing, what if i want to add "where sum(amount) > 1000"? I tried but im getting a invalid group function

select stock.id, stock.name, coalesce(sum(amount) , 0)
from stock
left join stock_detail 
   on stock.id = stock_detail.stock_id 
      and transact_date BETWEEN ('2018-06-15') and ('2018-06-16')
 where sum(amount) > 1000
group by stock.id

Comment: @webdev You need to add the predicate in `HAVING` clause: `... GROUP BY stock.id HAVING SUM(amount) > 1000`.